# C# localdb SHRINKDATABASE command from C# code

Tags: c#, localdb, shrink

I'm trying to shrink a LocalDb with Visual Studio 2017 Community. I have a Win7 client windows form application with a small database (~10MB of data) that results into 150MB database size due to LocalDb free space allocation.

I found this answer ([Executing Shrink on SQL Server database using command from linq-to-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543653/executing-shrink-on-sql-server-database-using-command-from-linq-to-sql)) that suggest to use the following code:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(@file)",
     new SqlParameter("@file", DatabaseTools.Instance.DatabasePathName)
);
```

`DatabaseTools.Instance.DatabasePathName` returns the filesystem location of my database from a singleton DatabaseTools class instance.

The code runs, but I keep getting this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot perform a shrinkdatabase operation inside a user transaction. Terminate the transaction and reissue the statement.'

I tried `COMMIT` before, but no success at all. Any idea on how to effectively shrink database from C# code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs for `ExecuteSqlCommand` say, *"If there isn't an existing local or ambient transaction a new transaction will be used to execute the command."*.

This is what's causing your problem, as you cannot call `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE` in a transaction. Which isn't really surprising, given what it does.

Use [the overload that allows you to pass a TransactionalBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand%28System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior,System.String,System.Object[]%29) and specify `TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction`:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction,
    "DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(@file)",
     new SqlParameter("@file", DatabaseTools.Instance.DatabasePathName)
);
```